# Remove a particular element in session storage angular8

Tags: angular, checkbox, session-cookies, session-storage

I have a list of directions namely

```
countryList = ["South","East","West"]

<div *ngFor="let country of countryList">

     <mat-checkbox (change)="checkBoxClicked(country, $event)">
        {{country}}
     </mat-checkbox>
</div>
```

shown as mat-checkbox. So when user selects a particular direction, I tried to store the same in session storage

```
 checkBoxClicked(list, event) {          
        if (event.checked) {
        sessionStorage.setItem("TestingSelectedPages",JSON.stringify({ 'Countries': list}));   

        }
            else {
                   //How to remove the same ???
             }

        }
```

For example, if the Session storage value is like this
[image]

I mean , if I uncheck a particular element, (Say , "South"), how to remove only South from the list and keep the others in session storage.

Comment: When you uncheck, what will be the value of `list`? If you are getting updated `list` then you can directly use the same statement that you have used in if condition.

Comment: @KaustubhKhare , i didnt thought this way. Thanks, it will work

Comment: Let me know if it works, I will add as an answer. So others will get help from that.

Comment: your idea works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting `list` which will be consist of updated values after either you checked or unchecked the checkbox. So you can directly use the `setItem` method to update session storage value.

```
checkBoxClicked(list, event) {          
   if (event.checked) {
     sessionStorage.setItem("TestingSelectedPages",JSON.stringify({ 'Countries': list}));   

   } else {
    sessionStorage.setItem("TestingSelectedPages",JSON.stringify({ 'Countries': list}));   
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You get your item in session storage, you add the new item or remove and update the session storage

```
 const current = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem(TestingSelectedPages));
 current.push(your new item to add);
 sessionStorage.setItem(TestingSelectedPages, JSON.stringify(current));
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, will work and let you know

Comment: yours will also work, but I can select only one accepted answer !. Sorry for that

Answer (score 1):

First thing first, it is highly recommended using types.
Also, JSON keys better be camelCased for best practice.
Now, I'd do the following

```
checkBoxClicked(list: string[], event: Event) {
    let directionList: string[] = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('TestingSelectedPages'));
    if (event.checked) {
        directionList.countries.push(event.value);
    }
    else {
        directionList = directionList.countries.filter((direction: string) => direction !== event.value)
    }
    sessionStorage.setItem("TestingSelectedPages", JSON.stringify({ 'countries': directionList }));
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: yours will also work, but I can select only one accepted answer !. Sorry for that